# Load WebView URL inside Notification Bar NSPopover

Tags: xcode, macos, webview, nspopover

I'm a noob OSX Developer having issues getting a WebView to load a URL when inside of a Custom View using NSPopover...My NSPopover is activated when a notification bar item is clicked.

This code is in my application delegate under 
"- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification":

`NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
    NSURLRequest*request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[_webView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];`

It works just fine if I move the WebView to any other window, but the WebView in my Custom View for this NSPopover displays as a blank page. Any ideas why? Any additional information you might need? Limitation of the CustomView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created the Outlet in IB for the UIWebView in your Custom View ?  and strung it together?

Comment: Exactly what was going on! Thanks so much. Should've known better haha